# Pyttsx3 problemas para hablar más de una vez seguida

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando hacer un asistente virtual en python utilizando los módulos pyttsx3. El problema es que mi método speak(audio) que utiliza pyttsx3 solo habla una vez y aunque tenga que hablar más de una vez seguida se queda callado despues del primer comando.

La verdad que he estado mirando por internet y nadie parece tener un problema parecido al que yo tengo y me estoy volviendo un poco loco. He mirado si puede ser problema de que el módulo no este bien instalado o algo pero parece que está todo en orden.

Os adjunto el código a ver si sabeis por que es. He buscado por internet pero nadie parece tener ese problema asique supongo que puede ser algún error en mi código:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[len(voices) - 2].id)


def speak(audio):
    print('Computer: ' + audio)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    speak('Hello Sir, I am your digital assistant LARVIS the Lady Jarvis!')
    speak('How may I help you?')
```

Comment: Hola UnaiLopez, he probado tu código y en mi caso todo funciona como cabe esperar,  no puedo reproducir tu problema... :( . Coloca un `print` entre la llamada a `say` y `runAndWait` y otro después de este a ver si al menos nos indica algo (se bloquea en alguna llamada). ¿Que sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: Perdon por no contestar antes, estaba en la universidad y no pude contestarte. Respecto a tus preguntas: estoy utilizando windows10 y acabo de hacer lo que me dijiste de los prints y resulta que se queda trabado en runAndWait(), es decir, el print después del runAndWait() no lo saca por pantalla. ¿Se te ocurre por que podría ser?, es muy extraño.

Comment: Por si te sirve también estoy utilizando la versión 3.7 de python y tengo ese mismo interprete seleccionado en mi proyecto de PyCharm que es la IDE que estoy utilizando.

Comment: Unai investigando he encontrado el mismo problema reportado, pero con OSX, en GitHub: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/22. En mi caso lo he probado en Linux (ArchLinux) y Python 3.7 y no puedo reproducirlo, por lo que tampoco puedo probar cosas. Ahora no tengo a mano Windows, pero voy a intentar probar en cuanto pueda, a ver si puedo reproducirlo.

Comment: Probe en windows lo que decian en ese link que me mandaste de llamarlo desde una funcion o desde una clase y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Finalmente he probado en Windows 10 con Python 3.7.3 y 3.6.4 y tampoco puedo reproducirlo.... Prueba a ejecutar el script directamente desde CMD y no desde el IDE, hay veces que ciertas advertencia / errores no se muestran, en mi caso, en linux, algunos warnigns de ALSA no se muestran en la terminal emulada del IDE. Prueba a cambiar la voz también, por si acaso... Es curioso y parece que no eres el único, pero no consigo reproducirlo...

Comment: Acabo de probar con el CMD y cambiando la voz y tampoco funciona. No se que más se puede probar...
También pregunté en stack overflow en ingles por si alguien sabia resolverlo y parece que nadie ni si quiera se a atrevido a contestarme jajaja

Comment: Al  terminar el proceso en el CMD me salió esto. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asistente.py", line 15, in <module>
    def speak(audio):
  File "asistente.py", line 12, in speak
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[len(voices) - 2].id)
  File "C:\Users\Unai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 188, in runAndWait
    self.proxy.runAndWait()
  File "C:\Users\Unai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 204, in runAndWait
    self._driver.startLoop()

Comment: File "C:\Users\Unai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 110, in startLoop
    time.sleep(0.05)